Ingresar otra clausula AND
Hola Tengo el siguiente codigo pero me gustaria meter otra clausula AND pues al colocarla al final esta no me resulta.
quisiera agregar esta linea AND
AND municipio = '$municipioe';
$consulta=mysql_query("SELECT id, nombre, identificacion, municipio, cargo, estadotrabajador, motivo_retiro, gabeta, gab, carpeta, color, foto, etiqueta, carnet, correo FROM tabla1 WHERE " . implode("  AND ", array_map(function($ele){
return "(nombre LIKE '$ele%' OR nombre LIKE '% $ele%' OR identificacion  LIKE '%$ele%' OR municipio  LIKE '%$ele%' OR cargo LIKE '%$ele%')";
}, explode(" ", $nompropietario))) . ";", $serv);


Porque no intentas colocarla al principio?

Deberías mostrar la consulta funcional, la consulta que quieres hacer y falla, y lo que esperas obtener. Lee [mre]

Hola. No se entiende qué es lo que quieres hacer. ¿Qué hay en $ele y cuál es el resultado final que quieres obtener? Además, aunque funcione, sería un código altamente vulnerable a ataques de  inyección SQL. Deberías escribir una consulta preparada poniendo marcadores y pasar los datos con el método bind correspondiente al controlador que estés usando: mysqli, PDO u otro.

Antes que todo (pregunto por las dudas): Entiendes que: true or true and false es distinto a (true or true) and false ????

Hola Eduardo, veo tu código y me da la sensación de que lo estas ofuscando y es por esta razón que no podes ver que, lograr lo que necesitas, se puede hacer aplicando más de lo mismo. Crea variables, separa la creación de filtros de la consulta. Vas a ver que al tener mejor organizado el código, la solución va a ser intuitiva.
